# ElasticSearch: groovy script to painless

Tags: elasticsearch

I wrote this script using groovy language (`datediff.groovy`):

```
(doc[secondDateField].date.millis - doc[firstDateField].date.millis) / 3600000
```

It works fine. Nevertheless, I'm intended to move these script to `painless` (`datediff.painless`). Nevertheless, I'm getting compilation error on straup:

```
[esn1] failed to load/compile script [datediff]: {
   "type" : "script_exception",
   "reason" : "compile error",
   "caused_by" : {
     "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
     "reason" : "Variable [secondDateField] is not defined."
   },
   "script_stack" : [
     "(doc[secondDateField].date.mil ...",
     "     ^---- HERE"
   ],
   "script" : "(doc[secondDateField].date.millis - doc[firstDateField].date.millis) / 3600000",
   "lang" : "painless"
}
```

It's telling me `secondDateField` is not defined. Could you help me in order to get it?

`secondDateField` is not the field named `secondDateField`. It's a script parameter (like `firstDateField`), and doc[parameter] should access to the field set in the `parameter` content. If `secondDateField = "fieldOne"`, `doc[secondDateField] => doc["fieldOne"]`...

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this in `Painless` if you're trying to convert it into **milliseconds** and also you're missing out the single quote `'` before and after the *field* name I'm afraid:

```
(doc['secondDateField'].date.millisOfSecond - doc['firstDateField'].date.millisOfSecond) / 3600000
```

millis should've been as *milliseconds* as per the [Lucene Date Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-scripting-expression.html#_date_field_api).

Hope this helps!

Comment: `secondDateField` is not the field named `secondDateField`. It's a parameterized script where it receives two parameters, and doc should access to the field set in the `secondDateField`. If `secondDateField = "fieldOne"`, `doc[secondDateField] => doc["fieldOne"]`

Comment: Not sure how painless handles a parameterized script though. Sorry about that!